# Beginner - Transform xml with xslt (Adding parent node)

Tags: xml, xslt

Alright all,

**XML looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order_Root>
   <Header Info="Some Info" Info2="More Info" Info3="More Info">
   <Order Number="1" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
   <Order Number="2" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
   <Order Number="3" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
   </Header>
</Order_Root>
```

**XSLT currently looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <xsl:variable name="url">
           <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>
            <xsl:text>.xml</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$url}">
            <SplitOrder>
                <xsl:copy-of select="parent::node()/Header"></xsl:copy-of>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </SplitOrder>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Results currently like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SplitOrder>
   <Order Number="1" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000"/>
   </Order>
</SplitOrder>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SplitOrder>
   <Order Number="2" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000"/>
   </Order>
</SplitOrder>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SplitOrder>
   <Order Number="3" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000"/>
   </Order>
</SplitOrder>
```

I have been trying for hours but no luck trying to get the header info on all three of the output xml. I am very much a beginner with xslt any help is appreciated. I am using Saxon xsl version 2.0.
**Resulting in:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SplitOrder>
    <Header Info="Some Info" Info2="More Info" Info3="More Info">
    <Order Number="1" Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
        <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000"/>
    </Order>
    </Header>
</SplitOrder>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Header` is actually the parent of your matched `Order` nodes. You could do `xsl:copy-of select=".." />` but that would end up copying all the child `Order` nodes too.

Instead, create a new node and copy the attributes, like so...

```
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$url}">
        <SplitOrder>
            <Header>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../@*" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </Header>
        </SplitOrder>
    </xsl:result-document>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a general approach, you can run the subtree containing the `Order` through a mode that makes sure only ancestors of it are copied through:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
            <SplitOrder>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*" mode="subtree">
                  <xsl:with-param name="subtree" select="ancestor-or-self::*[position() ne last()]" tunnel="yes"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </SplitOrder>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="subtree">
        <xsl:param name="subtree" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test=". intersect $subtree">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="subtree"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Order" mode="subtree">
        <xsl:param name="subtree" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select=".[. intersect $subtree]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the above doesn't have the `xsl:result-document` but you can of course add that back in with e.g.

```
    <xsl:template match="Order">
         <xsl:result-document href="{@Number}.xml">
            <SplitOrder>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*" mode="subtree">
                  <xsl:with-param name="subtree" select="ancestor-or-self::*[position() ne last()]" tunnel="yes"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </SplitOrder>
         </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
```